# What if a copyright registration service goes bust?

Tags: copyright, music

When I create a song I immediately upload it to dropbox. That way I can make sure I can recover it if my hard drive is failing (as i don't have redundancy) but also to show I have a tangible form of the song which is on dropbox as evidence.

There is also copyright registration services that will store the file, for example songrite, CCS (in the UK) etc.

My question is what happens if dropbox or CCS go bust? is my proof of having recorded it at a certain date gone?
And how should I mitigate it, is taking a screenshot enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Legally, such services have no special status. They're not necessary for copyright to exist, and their status as evidence is not in any way special.

This is one of those rare cases where a blockchain actually *does* make sense. Recently the idea of Non-Fungible Tokens has come up in the context of blockchains, and typically these are very accurately dated. NFT's can be sold, but that is not necessary for them to be created.